# Unity3D Выполнение скрипта на кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скрипт на врагах:

```
    public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 Player;
    private Vector2 PlayerDirection;
    public float Xdif;
    public float Ydif;
    private float speed;
    private float distance;
    private bool stun;
    private float stuntime;
    GameObject playerObj;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody2D;
    private bool isEnemyFear;
    public randomizer fear;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
  stuntime = 0;
  stun = false;
  speed = 6;
  playerObj = GameObject.Find ("Player");
  myRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
  distance = Vector2.Distance (Player, transform.position);
  Player = playerObj.transform.position;
  if (stuntime > 0) {
   stuntime -=Time.deltaTime;
  } else {
   stun = false;
  }
  if(fear.CheckFear()){
   EnemyFear();
  }
  else{
   EnemyAttack();
  }

    }
    void EnemyAttack(){

  if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
   Xdif = Player.x - transform.position.x;
   Ydif = Player.y - transform.position.y;
   PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
   myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
   Debug.Log("нападают");
  }    
    }

    void EnemyFear(){

  if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
   Xdif = Player.x + transform.position.x;
   Ydif = Player.y + transform.position.y;
   PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
   myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
   Debug.Log("убегают");
  }
  StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Playerhit){
  if (Playerhit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
   stun = true;
   stuntime = 1;
  }
    }
    IEnumerator Timer() {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
  isEnemyFear = false;
  StopCoroutine ("Timer");
    }

}
```

Скрипт на кнопке:

```
    public class randomizer : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isEnemyFear;

    public void CheckFear(){
  int rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
  if(rand > 35)
   isEnemyFear = true;
    }

}
```

Функция `CheckFear()` висит на кнопке. Сам скрипт находится в так называемом менеджере, не на врагах, не на игроке.
Сейчас `distance = Vector2.Distance (Player, transform.position);`
и `Xdif = Player.x - transform.position.x;
        Ydif = Player.y - transform.position.y;`
не могут рассчитаться правильно потому что transform.position берется менеджера. 
**Как `isEnemyFear = true` передать в скрипт на врагах?** Так как это сделано сейчас не работает.

Comment: А враг в игре у вас один или они волнами подходят? Если волнами то придется реализовывать перебор  с ближайшими и запускать вашу проверку для каждого. Алгоритмов выбора рядом находящихся объектов целое море, нужно выбирать под свою задачу какой больше подойдет.

Comment: враг не один, игра что-то вроде изометрической рпг, т.е. игрок ходит по карте и натыкается на врагов. Изменил скрипт и вопрос. Сможете что-то подсказать по такому случаю?

Answer (score 1):

наконец решил этот вопрос, вот код

Скрипт на врагах:

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 Player;
    private Vector2 PlayerDirection;
    public float Xdif;
    public float Ydif;
    private float speed;
    private float distance;
    private bool stun;
    private float stuntime;
    GameObject playerObj;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody2D;
    //private bool isEnemyFear;
    public randomizer fear;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        stuntime = 0;
        stun = false;
        speed = 6;
        playerObj = GameObject.Find ("Player");
        myRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
        distance = Vector2.Distance (Player, transform.position);
        Player = playerObj.transform.position;
        if (stuntime > 0) {
            stuntime -=Time.deltaTime;
        } else {
            stun = false;
        }
        if(fear.isEnemyFear){
            EnemyFear();
        }
        else{
            EnemyAttack();
        }

    }
    void EnemyAttack(){

        if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
            Xdif = Player.x - transform.position.x;
            Ydif = Player.y - transform.position.y;
            PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
            myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
            Debug.Log("нападают");
        }   
    }

    void EnemyFear(){

        if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
            Xdif = Player.x + transform.position.x;
            Ydif = Player.y + transform.position.y;
            PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
            myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
            //AudioController.Play( "zombie" ); 
            Debug.Log("убегают");
        }
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Playerhit){
        if (Playerhit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            stun = true;
            stuntime = 1;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Timer() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        fear.isEnemyFear = false;
        StopCoroutine ("Timer");
    }

}
```

Скрипт на кнопке:

```
public class randomizer : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isEnemyFear = false;

    public void CheckFear(){
  int rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
  if(rand > 35)
   isEnemyFear = true;
    }

}
```

Просьба прокомментировать насколько такое решение адекватно.
И не медленно ли оно?